# Jboss ServiceBindingManager and server.xml: ports and certificate

Tags: jboss

Using the ServiceBindingManager referencing the "sample-bindings.xml" configuration in the /conf/jboss-service.xml:

```
   <mbean code="org.jboss.services.binding.ServiceBindingManager"
     name="jboss.system:service=ServiceBindingManager">
     <attribute name="ServerName">myserver</attribute>
     <attribute name="StoreURL">${jboss.home.url}/docs/examples/binding-manager/sample-bindings.xml</attribute>
     <attribute name="StoreFactoryClassName">
       org.jboss.services.binding.XMLServicesStoreFactory
     </attribute>
   </mbean>
```

1) Having enabled the ServiceBindingManager does it mean the "server.xml" ports are overwritten by the sample-bindings.xml defined ports?

```
<!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
     and responses are returned. Documentation at :
     Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
     Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
     APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
     Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
-->
<Connector port="8080" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
     maxThreads="250" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
     emptySessionPath="true" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
     compression="on"
     compressionMinSize="2048"
     noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
     compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/javascript,application/x-javascript,text/css,text/plain"
     enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
     connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" server="server1" />

<!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
     This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the
     connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
     described in the APR documentation -->

<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="250" scheme="https" secure="true"
           maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
           emptySessionPath="true"
           address="${jboss.bind.address}"
           keystoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/server.keystore"
           keystorePass="xx"
           truststoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/server.keystore"
           truststorePass="xx"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" server="server1" />
```

2) If the server.xml ports are not relevant any more, how can the TLS server certificate still be used?

Answer (score 0):

After some googling, it does look like sample-bindings.xml *ports* will override server.xml ports related settings and is mainly used for running multiple instances of JBoss on the same server/machine.  On the SSL scertificate, if the keystores appear to be no longer found - you can add them as program arguments either in the JAVA_OPTS section of run.conf (I'm assuming you're using an older version of JBoss) or you can add them to the command line or script you use to start JBoss, for example:

`/home/jboss/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/bin/./run.sh -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=server.keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=server.keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=xx -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=xx  > /dev/null 2>&1 &`

Note, you'd need the correct paths to the files.

We use the same keystore/truststore program arguments at work on many Jboss instances.

Comment: Using these -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore and  -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore commandline Arguments does it override the keystoreFile and truststoreFile Properties int the Connector section of the server.xml file? At the end those arguments could just be System Properties which can be used in the program code, Does the application server itself access and use those arguments to handle certificates?

Comment: I *believe* but havent found proof that using sample-bindings.xml will override server.xml so you'd need to try it. As a test, you could use the -D params with a bad filename and check for the error in the server.log file, you could also do both, use a bad name in the -D and a bad name in the server.xml and see which one it complains about.  In our setup, we dont specify the keystore except as -D params and the app server uses them. Yes, you could also specify it directly as System.Properties in your code. Try it out either way and let me know how it goes!  I'll be happy to help more if I can!

Comment: We are getting a bit off topic here. I know the server.xml TLS-Connector as shown in Bullet 1) above is using the keystore and truststore for inbound connections to the webserver itself. And in Bullet 2) I want to learn how the heck the ServiceBindingManager is able to use the key- and trustsore from this TLS-Connector for totally different ports/services in the bindings.xml. I just miss here a piece of information on how this internally works.

Comment: Or in other words how is the - server.xml Connector 8443 (TLS)- in the service binding xml referenced. As incoming TLS connections are based on those server.xml TLS-Connector's keystoreFile and truststoreFile; surely using the service binding port instead.

Comment: You might try posting your question [here](https://developer.jboss.org/) in the JBoss developer forums - you're likely to get a much better answer to your questions